# How do I SQL order by distance when some users have null Lat Lng field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a members table and when results are shown I want to show closest users first, however some users don't have a location set yet which throws up an error.

```
SELECT ROUND(geography::Point(Lat, Long, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point("&SearchLat&", "&SearchLong&", 4326))/1000,0) as Distance FROM users
```

If a null field is encountered I get the following error.

`''geography::Point'' failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null.`

I want all users to display, but the ones closest first then those with no distance after.

Is there an easy way to remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all of the users with an unknown location at the north pole:

```
SELECT ROUND(geography::Point(COALESCE(Lat,89.9), COALESCE(Long,0), 4326).STDistance(
             geography::Point("&SearchLat&", "&SearchLong&", 4326))/1000,0) as Distance 
FROM users
```

Or off the coast of Africa:

```
SELECT ROUND(geography::Point(COALESCE(Lat,0), COALESCE(Long,0), 4326).STDistance(
             geography::Point("&SearchLat&", "&SearchLong&", 4326))/1000,0) as Distance
FROM users
```

Or pick some other default latitude and longitude such that they're almost certainly far away from the rest of your users.

Comment: Perfect, never used COALESCE before, seriously useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROUND(geography::Point(Lat, Long, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point("&SearchLat&",
"&SearchLong&", 4326))/1000,0) as Distance FROM users

WHERE Lat IS NOT NULL AND Long IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: But I want all users to display, but the ones closest first.

Comment: And where should the users be, which don't have a location. Because the distance is unknown!